# One-Way Mirrioring Two Storage Container Blobs with Power Automate

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

So I kinda figured this would be easy, and it just Kinda... hasn't been?

The flow seems simple:

TRIGGER: When a Blob Changes or Is Updated

1. Get the Blob File(s)
2. Write the blob content to the Companion Blob

Notes:

1. The blobs are in different locations
2. We're going to use the first blob as fallback if files don't load from the second one. (We know that randomly at some point we're going to have the certificate of the first blob's StaticWebApp changed from underneath us, which is going to break things to an extent, hence the redundancy)
3. The hope around functionality is just hopefully to keep blob 2 to continue to have everything blob 1 has. It's okay if blob2 has *more* I'll handle the delete thing later.

Here is the flow itself, the problem is, when I add a folder or image to the /$web folder, it just doesn't trigger.

(PS, If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears)

[image: The Flow in Question]

Answer (score 0):

> If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears)

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I have used Azure Logic Apps :

**`Design:`**

Firstly created a trigger:

[image]

Then Get the content:

[image]

Then changed the connection like below:

[image]

Then used create blob:

[image]

This works if both are in different locations also.

**`Output:`**

After editing/adding:

[image]

[image]

In another its created:

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@body('Get_blob_content_(V2)')",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/test2",
                        "name": "@triggerBody()?['Name']",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['Path']))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmdGVzdA==",
                        "maxFileCount": 100
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmdGVzdA==": "/test"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "azureblob_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-1",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me and it will work for you too.

Comment: To me, no triggering means that maybe my connection is bad or my trigger is bad? That's one of the big difference between power apps and logic apps is connection and connection references. I'll make it in logic apps and check back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alright so! Got the trigger working. Two Problems: 

1. Turns out, it doesn't trigger if I change a blob "inside" of a "folder" (I know blobs dont really have folders, just names with slashes in them that get interpreted as folders in some cases). Does that make sense? Am I missing something here? Everytime I add a file blob to /$web/site/ the trigger runs and get's shown as 'skipped' ... versus when I add a file directly to /$web the trigger runs. 

2. I'm getting a 404 on the run when I add an image directly to /$web

Inputs: https://i.imgur.com/ULWcINw.png

outputs:

Comment: Glad that the trigger worked, Yes, slashes are important, not sure why got 404

Comment: Is there any reasonably easy way to make this recursive? So anything I put in /$web/test/folder ALSO get's moved?

Comment: You need to just add slashes and the folder names, thats it